# "The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the class 'AuthResult'" when trying to use .createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am fairly new to app development and am having trouble with one error in my code.

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'main.dart';

void main() => runApp(Signup());

//Stateless: Cannot be changed during runtime
//Can only be called once
class Signup extends StatelessWidget {
  
  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.pink,
      ),
      home: SignUp(title: 'Sign up!'),
    );
  }
}


class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  SignUp({Key key, this.title, this.uid}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;
  final String uid;

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState();
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  
  TextStyle style = TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Montserrat', fontSize: 20.0);

 
  TextEditingController first_entry = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController last_entry = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController email_entry = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController password_entry = new TextEditingController();

  PersistentBottomSheetController _sheetController;
  bool _loading = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    final FirstName = TextFormField(
      controller: first_entry,
      validator: (value) {
        if(value.isEmpty){
          return 'Please enter your first name';
        }
        return null;
      },
      obscureText: false,
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "First Name",
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final LastName = TextFormField(
      controller: last_entry,
      validator: (value) {
        if(value.isEmpty){
          return 'Please enter your last name';
        }
        return null;
      },
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Last Name",
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final email = TextFormField(
      controller: email_entry,
      validator: (value) {
        if(value.isEmpty){
          return 'Please enter your email';
        }
        return null;
      },
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Email",
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final pass = TextFormField(
      controller: password_entry,
      obscureText: true,
      validator: (value) {
        if(value.isEmpty){
          return 'Please enter your password';
        }
        return null;
      },
      style: style,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: "Password",
          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
          border:
          OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32.0))),
    );

    final Signingup = Material(
      elevation: 5.0,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      color: Color(0xff01A0C7),
      child: MaterialButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 15.0, 20.0, 15.0),
        onPressed: () async {
          print(first_entry.text);
          print(last_entry.text);
          print(email_entry.text);
          try {
           FirebaseAuth.instance
               .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email_entry.text,
                  password: password_entry.text)
               .then((authResult) => Firestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .document(authResult.user.uid)
                  .setData({
                    "uid": authResult.user.uid,
                    "fname": first_entry.text,
                    "surname": last_entry.text,
                    "email": email_entry.text,
           })
           .then((result) =>  {
               Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) => MyHomePage(
                     title:
                     first_entry
                         .text +
                         "'s Tasks",
                     uid: authResult.user.uid,
                   )),
                   (_) => false),
               first_entry.clear(),
               last_entry.clear(),
               email_entry.clear(),
               password_entry.clear(),
               }));
            setState(() {});
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyHomePage()),
            );
            }
          catch (e) {
            print('Error while logging in $e'); // #debug
          }
        },
        child: Text("Sign me up!",
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            style: style.copyWith(
                color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      ),
    );
    return Scaffold(
     body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 235.0,
                    child: Image.asset(
                      "images/SignUp.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.contain,
                    ),
                  ),
                  FirstName,
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  LastName,
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  email,
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                  pass,
                  SizedBox(height: 39.0),
                  Signingup,
                  SizedBox(height: 25.0),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget?.title ?? ''),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Container(
          height: 45.0,
          color: Colors.pink[100],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The error I get is "The getter 'uid' isn't defined for the class 'AuthResult'" whenever there is a "currentUser.uid." I used the code from https://github.com/samsam-026/flutter-example/tree/master/lib so I am unsure why it is not working. I have tried getUid(), but I am not sure if I am doing it right as it still gives me an error. Any tips are appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With recent updates [(after v0.12.0) of firebase_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#0120) plugin update, the sign in methods return AuthResult instead of FirebaseUser, so you must get user from authresult.

```
           FirebaseAuth.instance
               .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email_entry.text,
                  password: password_entry.text)
               .then((authResult) => Firestore.instance
                  .collection("users")
                  .document(authResult.user.uid) //returns auth result so you should get user.uid from auth result
                  .setData({
                    "uid": authResult.user.uid,
                    "fname": first_entry.text,
                    "surname": last_entry.text,
                    "email": email_entry.text,
           })
           .then((result) =>  {
               Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
               context,
               MaterialPageRoute(
                   builder: (context) => MyHomePage(
                     title:
                     first_entry
                         .text +
                         "'s Tasks",
                     uid: authResult.user.uid,
                   )),
                   (_) => false),
               first_entry.clear(),
               last_entry.clear(),
               email_entry.clear(),
               password_entry.clear(),
               }));
```

Comment: Oh wow, it worked nicely, thank you. I would have never gotten that! Would you happen to know if there seems to be anything wrong with my code? I was able to run it but when I try to save a first and last name to my firebase database, it does not save. If not, I can always ask another question!

Comment: Sure, I edited my question. I added the whole sign up button code, which is the only code I changed to incorporate firebase (in my homepage I only added final String uid so I could use uid in this code). I also added an example of the first name entry. The other entries like email, password, and last name are very similar. Let me know if you need any more code! Thank you for your time, I've been stuck for quite sometime

Comment: complete runable code would be helpful, however
1. Have you logged and check if the controllers are providing the entered value
2. Did you check what is saved in your database if uid is saved ?(screenshot of database would be helpful)
If uid is saved and only fname and lname are null then you are not getting proper value from textfield

Comment: Now I have an odd problem, I was trying to print my values from the TextFormField and added  print(first_entry.text);  print(last_entry.text);  print(email_entry.text); right below onPressed: () async {
I then ran my code on Android-Studio's terminal and I saw that it printed correctly and when I checked my database, my information saved! I removed the print statements and the next time I entered information, it did not save. I found it odd as I was just printing to the termina instead of saving it anywhere. I will also update my question again with the code and screenshot

Comment: try saving the values of text fields in variable on button press, then try debugging with breakpoint ahd check the values.

Comment: Thank you for your help and so sorry, I did a simple mistake and did not connect my IOS to firebase correctly but was connected to my Android correctly, explaining why it worked for Android but not IOS
So sorry again but thank you for all your help! You pointing out I should check for my values guided me to the right direction so thank you!

Comment: Great. Glad it helped.